# How to pass list of enum to fragment?

Tags: android, arraylist, enums, fragment, bundle

How do I pass a list of Enums to a fragment via a bundle? I can pass a single Enum via putSerialisable. But not a list of Enums.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you have enum like this:

```
enum SimpleEnum {
  ONE ,TWO, THREE
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
    ArrayList<String> enums = new ArrayList<>();
    enums.add(SimpleEnum.ONE.name());
    enums.add(SimpleEnum.TWO.name());
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArrayList("enums", enums);
```

To retrieve enums back use the following:

```
List<String> enums = args.getStringArrayList("enums");

for (String enumName : enums) {
    SimpleEnum e = SimpleEnum.valueOf(enumName);
}
```